# SAS Rounding by thousandths place

Tags: sas, rounding

I have been asked to write some code in SAS that rounds a number up but only if the digit in the thousandth place is greater than one.  For example, 78.858 would obviously round up to 78.86 but would also want to take 78.852 and round up to 78.86.

Comment: What do you want to do with values like `78.8514` or `78.8515`?  Do you want both of those to round up to `78.86`? Or neither? Or perhaps only the second one?

Comment: I would want both those to round up to 78.86 also

Comment: What kind of silk-road shenanigans is this rounding? Re @Toms numbers, so you want up rounding when thousandths digit >=1? (His .###4 and .####5 are in the ten-thousandths)

Comment: LOL I'm in agreement with you on the 'shenanigans' part but this is how they are asking me to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do it in two operations. Use the normal ROUND() function.  Then check how much it changed.  And then based on that difference decide whether or not to add an extra hundredth.

Example:

```
data have;
  input x ;
cards;
78.858
78.86
78.852
78.8515
;

data want;
  set have;
  round=round(x,0.01);
  diff = x-round;
  if diff > 0.001 then round=round+0.01 ;
run;
```

Results

```
OBS       x       round     diff

 1     78.8580    78.86    -.0020
 2     78.8600    78.86    0.0000
 3     78.8520    78.86    0.0020
 4     78.8515    78.86    0.0015
```